# How to update a row from a different row data using laravel

Tags: laravel, sum

By clicking verify button I want the status of payment to change from pending to verified, then the pending amount (in payments table) to sum up with the wallet balance amount in users table and the final balance updated in users table using Laravel. This is my controller. Please help

```
public function verify_payment($user_id,$payment_data,$id){

        $wallet = Mpesa::findOrFail($id);
        $wallet->status = 'verified';
        if($wallet->save()){
            flash(__('Payment has been approved successfully'))->success();
            return redirect()->route('all.payments');
        }
        $top_up = User::findOrFail($user_id);
        $top_up->amount = $payment_data['amount'];
        $top_up->balance = $top_up->balance + $payment_data['amount'];
        $top_up->save();

        flash(__('Something went wrong'))->error();
        return back();
    }
```

Comment: You should not call return statement until the payment table get updated

Answer (score 0):

public function verify_payment($user_id,$payment_data,$id){

```
    $wallet = Mpesa::findOrFail($id);
    $wallet->status = 'verified';
    if($wallet->save()){
        flash(__('Payment has been approved successfully'))->success();
    }
    $top_up = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    $top_up->amount = $payment_data['amount'];
    $top_up->balance = $top_up->balance + $payment_data['amount'];
    $top_up->save();

    flash(__('Something went wrong'))->error();
    return redirect()->route('all.payments');
}
```